# Can't run jstack -l against my java application

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

My application got stuck, then I wanted to check the thread status. But I couldn't take a thread dump via jstack -l 33822 from my application..

```
Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

Then I used -F to attempt to take a thread dump. I got an error as following:

```
    Attaching to process ID 33822, please wait...
    Debugger attached successfully.
    Server compiler detected.
    JVM version is 23.21-b01
    Deadlock Detection:
    sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.UnmappedAddressException: 3780320
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.checkPage(PageCache.java:208)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.getData(PageCache.java:63)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readBytes(DebuggerBase.java:217)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readCInteger(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:482)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readCompOopAddressValue(DebuggerBase.java:459)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readCompOopHandle(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:442)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxAddress.getCompOopHandleAt(LinuxAddress.java:125)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Oop.getKlassForOopHandle(Oop.java:231)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.ObjectHeap.newOop(ObjectHeap.java:380)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread.getThreadObj(JavaThread.java:331)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread.getCurrentParkBlocker(JavaThread.java:383)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:82)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:39)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:52)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:136)
            at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:102)
    sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.UnmappedAddressException: 10
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.checkPage(PageCache.java:208)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.getData(PageCache.java:63)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readBytes(DebuggerBase.java:217)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readCInteger(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:482)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readCompOopAddressValue(DebuggerBase.java:459)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readCompOopHandle(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:442)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxAddress.getCompOopHandleAt(LinuxAddress.java:125)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Oop.getKlassForOopHandle(Oop.java:231)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.ObjectHeap.newOop(ObjectHeap.java:356)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.NarrowOopField.getValue(NarrowOopField.java:44)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.OopUtilities.threadOopGetParkBlocker(OopUtilities.java:294)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread.getCurrentParkBlocker(JavaThread.java:385)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:82)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:39)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:52)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:136)
            at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:102)
    Can't print deadlocks:10
```

Is it a [defect](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7012079) of JVM?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the threaddump isn't happening anyway? We get this error but we still get a thread dump after a small wait

Comment: But that thread dump is corrupted and has no information.